# Fitting linear model using PolynominalFeatures

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I want to create some random data and try to improve my model with PolynominalFeatures, however I'm facing little troubles with doing so.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

#create some artificial data
x=np.linspace(-1,1,1000) 
x=pd.array(random.choices(x,k=1000))                                  
y=x**2+np.random.randn(1000)
#divide sample
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.5)

#define data frame to futher use for PolynomialFeatures
df=pd.DataFrame([x_train,x_test])
df=df.transpose()
data = df
# perform a polynomial features transform of the dataset
trans = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
data = trans.fit_transform(data)
model = sm.OLS(y_train,data).fit()
```

And then I get error : `ValueError: unrecognized data structures: <class 'pandas.core.arrays.numpy_.PandasArray'> / <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Do you have any ideas what should be done to make my regression work properly ?

Answer (score 0):

use `to_numpy()` function to convert pandas array to numpy array

```
model = sm.OLS(y_train.to_numpy(),data).fit()
```